# SQL query statement

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

How can I change from

```
SID Name Math English French
1   Sam  16   17      19
2   Tom  18   14      12
3   Al   90   33      2
```

to:

```
SID subject   Mark
1   Math      16
1   English   17
1   French    19
2   Math      18
2   English   14
2   French    12
3   Math      90
3   English   33
3   French    2
```

using SQL (MYsql and MS Access if possible) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT sid, 'Math' as subject, math as mark
FROM your_table
UNION ALL
SELECT sid, 'English' as subject, english as mark
FROM your_table
UNION ALL
SELECT sid, 'French' as subject, french as mark
FROM your_table
```

But the root cause of your problem is a wrong database design. Those subjects shouldn't be columns in the first place and should be stored in a table very much like your desired output.

**Edit**

So what does it do?

```
SELECT sid, 'Math' as subject, math as mark
FROM your_table
```

Returns the `sid` column, a "virtual" column with the hardcoded value `'Math'` that is given the name `subject`. As you have not stored the value `'Math'` somewhere, this had to be hardcoded. Then at last it also selects the column `math` using the name `mark` instead. Note the difference between `math` and `'Math'` - one is a column the other one a string literal because of the single quotes.

This is done for all three subjects (if you had four subjects, you'd need four parts in the UNION)

The UNION ALL combines all three SELECTs into one single query. andr solution (which has been downvoted by someone who didn't understand it) makes this even clearer by explicitely putting that into a derived table (or inline view).

Run each SELECT on its own to see what the individual parts are doing.

The part `as mark` is called a "column alias" and can also be used to retrieve columns with the same name from different tables in a join and still have unique names in the result set.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: oops, same answer at the same time. Do you want me to delete my post? Anyway, +1 to you because you was faster than me :)

Comment: the problem is i have it as an excel sheet and i want to convert it to access database

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name three same answers at the same time :)

Comment: is it possible to provide me with a little more explanation :)
BTW i tried it and it worked like a charm
thanks!

Comment: @a-horse-with-no-name: you are great!, -not to mention rock-
thanks man :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT SID,'Math' subject, Math Mark
FROM table
UNION ALL
SELECT SID,'English' subject, English Mark
FROM table
UNION ALL
SELECT SID,'French' subject, French Mark
FROM table
```

Comment: three same answers at the same time :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a pivot table:

http://www.ehow.com/i/#article_5336679

Hope this helps

Comment: It should be stated that in almost all simple SQL schemata, the need to create a pivot table at all indicates a badly designed database. If you're having to, in effect, shift to a different schema in a query, just to get usable data, that's a problem. In this case I would ask - what happens when a new course is added? I'm assuming this is probably for an assignment though, so I won't spend any more time proselytizing good database design!

Comment: Agreed. Sometimes, a separate model needs to be made and updated in parallel.

Comment: Oh I love crazy needlessly complex queries to be sure, they're fun. But the real world demands practicality over SQL induced pleasure!

Comment: Sometimes one has no control over the form in which one receives the data.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server 2005 or higher you can use [UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx#CodeSpippet4):

```
SELECT
  SID,
  Subject,
  Mark
FROM (
  SELECT SID, Math, English, French
  FROM atable
) s
  UNPIVOT (
    Mark FOR Subject IN (Math, English, French)
  ) u
```

Comment: I'm afraid i can't try this since i'm using MS Access and MYsql :(

Comment: I see, thanks for the details. It's possible that I'll remember it when answering your next question, but it would be great if you tagged your questions accordingly too. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from
( select sid, 'Math' as subject, math as mark from t
  union all
  select sid, 'English' as subject , English as Mark from t
  union all
  select sid, 'French' as subject, French as mark from t
) order by 1;
```

Should do the trick

Comment: Whoever downvoted that: that was stupid because it is a completely valid and correct solution

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from (
select SID, 'Math' as subject, math as mark from table  
union
select SID, 'English' as subject, English as mark from table  
union
select SID, 'French' as subject, french as mark from table  
) order by sid asc
```

where table  =

```
SID Name Math English French
1   Sam  16   17      19
2   Tom  18   14      12
3   Al   90   33      2
```