# Vim escape characters in functions

Tags: regex, vim

how can I escape the regexp `\([''"]\)\(.\{-}\)\1` and `*test`
in the following function

```
:%s/.*/\=substitute(submatch(0),"\([''"]\)\(.\{-}\)\1","*test","g")/
```

the first regex matches anything between quotation in each line and replace it with what ever matches the second regexp at the same line

thanks,
Best

Edit:
example:

```
select "foo" as subject from table where [subject_test]=true
union
select "bar" as subject from table where [subject_test]=true
```

should become

```
select "foo" as subject from table where [subject_foo]=true
union
select "bar" as subject from table where [subject_bar]=true
```

Comment: can you pls give an example(s), what kind of line do you have, and what result you want to get?

Comment: @Kent is the example clear? the regexp `*test` needs to be modified, but that's a different issue

Comment: Just keep in mind that parsing SQL with regexes will lead you to paths with dangerous dragons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if I understand your question correctly.

When using the function `substitute()` there are other rules for pattern than when using e.g. `:s///`.
See this: [:h substitute()](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#substitute%28%29)
Some parts from that:

> ...
>   But the matching with {pat} is **always done like the 'magic' option is
>   set** and 'cpoptions' is empty (to make scripts portable).
>   'ignorecase' is still relevant.  'smartcase' is not used.
>   ...
>   Note that some codes in {sub} have a special meaning
>   |sub-replace-special|.    For example, to replace something with "\n"
>   (two characters), use "\\n" or '\n'.

It's not clearly how to use special regexp codes but they should be used with double backslash if you are using double quotes for the pattern string, `"\\"` means the character `\`, and is the same as `'\'`.
These should be equivalent when using the **function** substitute():
`'\([a-z]\)'`
`"\\([a-z]\\)"`
And my favorite, using `\v` ("very magic") so I don't have to backslash some regexp expressions:
`"\\v([a-z])"`

Your example should then be (**I have NOT considered if your pattern is correct or not**)

```
substitute(submatch(0), '\v([''"])(.{-})\1', "*test", "g")
Or:
substitute(submatch(0), "\\v(['\"])(.{-})\\1", "*test", "g")
```

The tricky part is that in the function substitute() you are using the pattern as a string, that is not the situation when normally using pattern in the command line in e.g. `:s///`.

---

**EDIT (again due to comment by OP):**
Can't say that I understand the use of your example, but I couldn't resist to try to fix it with an ex command like the one in your question (I'm trying to learn about VIM at the same time). Here is a command that works, and gives the result you want, but again, I don't understand what the use is.
But it seems that the question is really to learn how to escape regexp in a string.
If the "string" is always before what to substitute (and only substitutes one `test` for each ""):

```
:%s/\v"([^"]+)".*_\zstest/\1/g
```

**Explanation**

- `\zs` = start match, `\v` = use "very magic"
- `"([^"]+)"` "match" all characters except `"` (minimum 1) between `"` and `"`
  (the "real match" hasn't started yet, but the match in the parentheses will be as submatch number 1 anyway)
- `.*` all characters up to next expression:
- `_\zstest` "match" `_test`, but `\zs` makes the "real match" to start after that, so it's only `test` that will be substituted.
- `/\1/` replace with submatch number 1

**changed** This wasn't "safe", I added some longer match (from **@Kent**'s answer), and also make sure only lines that have `"<any characters>"` are processed.
If the "string" can be before or after what to substitute

```
:g/\v"[^"]+"/y w | s/\v\[\w*_\zstest\ze\]/\=matchstr(@w, '\v"\zs[^"]+\ze"')/g
```

**Explanation**

- `\v` = "very magic"
- `g/\v"[^"]+"` use lines that have `"<some text>"`
- `/y w` yank line to reg. `w` (instead of using getline())
- `|` to have one more command
- `\zs` = start match, `\ze` = end match (quicker than using look-ahead etc.)
- `\w` same as using `[0-9A-Za-z_]`
- `\[\w*_\zstest\ze\]` "match" `[<almost any characters>_test]`, but the "real match" to substitute is `test` because of the `\zs` and `\ze`
- `matchstr(str, match)` returns the `match` in `str`
- `matchstr(@w, '\v"\zs[^"]+\ze"')` get the characters between `"` and `"` from the line (using reg `w`)
- ... and use that to replace the matched `test`
- `/g` do it for all occurrences of `[<almost any characters>_test]` in the line

Comment: I added a solution for the example in the question, although I think the purpose of the question is more to learn to use pattern in strings, and how to properly escape regexp expressions.

Comment: the use is to write an SQL script to normalizing a pivoted table, check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814534/sql-query-statement

Comment: anyway, it's a different story than vim (an SQL story hehe)

Comment: wow, i marked the question as answered before the edit because it answers the escaping part, but you provided me with your edit with the full solution, thanks a lot

Comment: can you please explain `:%s/\v"([^"]+)".*_\zstest/\1/g`

Comment: I have explained it now, but I think you should have a look in the manuals, my explanation was more for people that stumble in here when googling :) From mine and @Kent's explanations (he have done a lot in some of your threads) I think you have a good start to read manuals and do some testing. Ans as Kent says, when it is so complex it would be better to have it in a function.

Answer (score 1):

is this ok for you?

```
%s/\[.\{-}_\zstest\ze\]/\=split(getline('.'), '"')[1]/
```

this works too (with your example), and straightforward:

```
%s/\[subject_test\]/\="[subject_".split(getline("."),'"')[1]."]"/
```

Comment: actually no, I just need to learn how to escape the characters not to use different functions, your suggested solution doesn't use character escaping, thanks Kent :)

Comment: your substitute() actually does NOT do what you are expecting. anyway, you could check magic/very magic to skip some escaping. `:h \v`

Comment: i need this
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Alternate_delimiters_for_the_replace_command
but it's not working for my example

Comment: split() can be used only for a specific case (text between 2 quotations) right?, i want it to be more dynamic where i can use regexp to determinate the replacement if it's something more complicated than text between 2 quotations, that's why i trying to use substitute()

Comment: if you have **more dynamic** requirement, I suggest writing a function. You are free to implement what you want there.

Answer (score 1):

To escape characters which are using in a substitute function I use `escape()`

```
Escape the characters in {chars} that occur in {string} with a backslash.

Example: 
     :echo escape('c:\program files\vim', ' \')  
Results in:  
    c:\\program\ files\\vim
```

For you example you can use `escape('\([''"]\)\(.\{-}\)\1','\')`.
This will expand to: `\\(['"]\\)\\(.\\{-}\\)\\1`

Answer (score 0):

In VimL, single-quoted strings don't interpolate backslashes, and double-quoted strings do.

So, note the difference between `:echo '\'` and `:echo "\\"`.  In your example, you used double quotes, and since you're not turning off magic, you have a ton of escaping to do.  See `:help magic`... Since I found out about `\v`, people tell me I'm much more pleasant to be around.